# Eclipse wont auto complete/auto compile?

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation

I'm trying to change the port this server runs on via eclipse but no matter what I do it doesn't seem to autocompile/autocomplete my java file? Any ideas?

Comment: I have dozens of ideas; far too many to just start listing in the hopes that one will fix your problem.  You need to give way more context than this.  What have you tried?  How is your project configured?  What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 3):

1. For auto-build, go to **Project->Build Automatically**. Build automatically should be checked for auto build to happen.
2. For auto-complete(content assist) go to **Windows->Preferneces**. In there follow **Java->Editor->Content Assist** int he left tree and configure as you feel like.

Comment: Also need to check if the project has errors. It if does, the thing WILL NOT build automatically until they are corrected.

Comment: Right. That the OP must see in the Problems view

Comment: You also have to be sure that you are in a Java project and the source  folder being mark as it.