# Fixing a problem in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have this problem with my Eclipse:

When I create a new type and I write "." after it's name to get all the methods that relate to it, nothing happens.

For example:

```
int[] exmp= new int [5];
exmp.?
```

I don't get any of the methods that relate to array.

Another example:

```
Public class Example{
 private int example;
  this.?
```

I don't get an automatic completion for this.example

Does somenoe know how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Check this question to see if it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373993/eclipse-wont-auto-complete-auto-compile  you can also use ctrl+space to open the menu

Comment: I'll be happy to hear an explanation for the close voting.

Comment: What eclipse are you using?  Also, if you type "exmp." then hit ctrl+ space, does it show up?

Comment: @ Joseph: I use Helios Service Release 2, And no, It does not show up/

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from [this helpful link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/content-assist-ctrl-space-is-not-working-eclipse/).  This fixed it for me about 2 hours ago.

> Configure Eclipse’s content assist, go
>   “Preferences>Java>Editor>Content
>   Assist>Advanced“. Make sure “Other
>   Java Proposals” is ticked

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps related to the build path.
I've tried this after changing the location of my android sdk. My project properties/Libraries was still pointing to the wrong location. Editing it with the correct path fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got your Auto Activation settings turned on?

You need to make sure that the "." character is present - I normally enter all letters on the keyboard so I get content assist quickly. You can see it in the "Auto activation triggers for Java" box below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Java editor? It sounds like you are just using Eclipse text editor. Try saving the file as *.java and reopening. That should make sure you are using the right editor.